# CSS doesn't have effect on JavaFX GUI

Tags: css, javafx

My CSS code isn't doing anything to the look of the elements for the JavaFX application I have. I've noticed that the lines of code in the CSS document say "Unknown property" and are highlighted in yellow. I tried to uninstall and then reinstall e(fx)clipse but that didn't help. Here's the code

CSS

```
.header-one {
    -fx-stroke-width: 4;
    -fx-fill: 99000;
}
```

Java

```
Label patronHeader = new Label("Current Patron");
patronHeader.getStyleClass().add("header-one");
```

What should I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you use css elements, that a Label does not support:

Visit this site for more information on what you can set on Labeled controls:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled

Answer (score 0):

`-fx-stroke-width` and `-fx-fill` are not supported CSS properties for a [`Label`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#label).

You need

```
.header-one {
    -fx-text-fill: #990000 ;
}
.header-one .text {
    -fx-stroke-width: 4 ;
}
```